# Custom Ordering of SELECT Results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a Pro*C query, but this question should be general SQL. My research has been a dead end, but I think I'm missing something.

Suppose my server has an array of students' names, `{"Alice","Charlie","Bob"}`. I query the `Student_Ids` table for the students' ID numbers:

```
    SELECT id_no FROM student_ids
        WHERE student_name IN ('Alice','Charlie','Bob');
```

To simplify server-side processing, I want to sort the result set in the same order as the students' names. In other words, the result set would be `{alice_id_no, charlie_id_no, bob_id_no}` regardless of the actual ordering of the table or the behavior of any particular vendor's implementation.

The only solution I can think of is:

```
    . . .
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN student_name='Alice'   THEN 0
             WHEN student_name='Charlie' THEN 1
             WHEN student_name='Bob'     THEN 2 END;
```

but that seems extremely messy and cumbersome when trying to dynamically generate/run this query.

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE** I gave a terrible example by pre-sorting the students' names. I changed the names to be deliberately unsorted. In other words, I want to sort the names in a non-ASC or DESC-friendly way.

**UPDATE II** Oracle, but for knowledge's sake, I am looking for more general solutions as well.

Comment: Don't you mean `CASE WHEN student_name = 'Charlie' THEN 0 WHEN student_name = 'Alice' THEN 1 WHEN student_name = 'Bob' THEN 2 END`? Plus, the expression you've given is for your sample data equivalent to `ORDER BY student_name`...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: For knowledge's sake, MySQL has a FIND_IN_SET function which could be used to sort results by comma separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` expression you've given for your sample data is equivalent to `ORDER BY student_name`. Is that what you intended?

If you want a custom ordering that is not alphabetical, I think you might have meant something like this:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE
      WHEN student_name = 'Alice' THEN 0
      WHEN student_name = 'Charlie' THEN 1
      WHEN student_name = 'Bob' THEN 2
   END;
```

You can use a derived table as well, that holds the names as well as the ordering you want. This way you only have to put the names in a single time:

```
SELECT S.id_no
FROM
   student_ids AS S
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT Name = 'Alice', Seq = 0 FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL SELECT 'Bob', 2 FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL SELECT 'Charlie', 1 FROM DUAL
   ) AS N
      ON S.student_name = N.Name
ORDER BY
   N.Seq;
```

You could also put them into a temp table, but in Oracle that could be somewhat of a pain.

Comment: Updated the question. I pre-sorted the names without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this?

```
order by student_name
```

To do a custom sort, you only need one `case`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN student_name = 'Alice' THEN 1
               WHEN student_name = 'Bob' THEN 2
               WHEN student_name = 'Charlie' THEN 3
               ELSE 4
          END)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not this :

SELECT id_no FROM student_ids
        WHERE student_name IN ('Alice','Bob','Charlie')
ORDER BY student_name

Answer (score 0):

You can `ORDER BY` any columns, not necessary those in `SELECT` list or `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT id_no 
FROM student_ids 
WHERE student_name IN ('Alice','Bob','Charlie)
ORDER BY id_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a table to hold the sort priorities then you can use the sort_priorities in whatever query you want (and easily update the priorities):

```
CREATE TABLE student_name_sort_priorities (
   student_name VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT student_name_sort_priority__pk PRIMARY KEY,
   sort_priority NUMBER(10)  CONSTRAINT student_name_sort_priority__nn NOT NULL
                             CONSTRAINT student_name_sort_priority__u  UNIQUE
);
```

(If you want two values to be equivalently sorted then don't include the `UNIQUE` constraint.)

```
INSERT INTO student_name_sort_priorities VALUES ( 'Alice',   0 );
INSERT INTO student_name_sort_priorities VALUES ( 'Charlie', 2 );
INSERT INTO student_name_sort_priorities VALUES ( 'Bob',     1 );
```

Then you can join the sort priority table with the `student_ids` table and use the extra column to perform ordering:

```
SELECT id_no
FROM   student_ids s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       student_name_sort_priorities p
       ON (s.student_name = p.student_name)
ORDER BY
       sort_priority NULLS LAST;
```

I've used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that if a name is not contained on the `student_name_sort_priorities` table then it does not restrict the rows returned from the query; `NULLS LAST` is used in the ordering for a similar reason - any student names that aren't in the sort priorities table will return a `NULL` sort priority and be placed at the end of the ordering. If you don't want this then just use `INNER JOIN` and remove the `NULLS LAST`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 'table of varchar' type like the build-in below:

```
TYPE dbms_debug_vc2coll is table of varchar2(1000);
```

test:

```
SQL> select customer_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name from customers where cust_first_name in
  2  (select column_value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Frederic','Markus','Dieter')));

CUSTOMER_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME      CUST_LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------- --------------------
        154 Frederic             Grodin
        149 Markus               Rampling
        152 Dieter               Matthau
```

That seems to force the order, but that might just be bad luck. I'm not really a sql expert.
The execution plan for this uses 'collection iterator' instead of a big 'or' in the typical:

```
select customer_id, cust_first_name, cust_last_name from customers where cust_first_name in ('Frederic','Markus','Dieter');
```

hth, Hein.